# Give every angular material checkbox and ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, checkbox, pug

I am currently having a problem:

I need to create `md-checkboxes` from a Database. This part works fine with `ng-repeat`. But I am having a problem reading those checkboxes. 
Every entry in the Database has its own unique ID (I am using RethinkDB) so I thought I just can apply this as an ID.

```
md-card(ng-repeat="n in ideas")
md-card-content
span
md-checkbox(type="checkbox" id='n.id') {{n.idea}}
```

I am working with Jade / Pug as View Engine.
But how am I now able to read out all checkboxes at once?
I tried many methods like looping through all `ElementsByTagName("md-checkbox")` and than with a for to read the checked value but it always returns undefined.

```
 const checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("md-checkbox");
 console.log(checkboxes) //works fine, prints all checkboxes
 for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    console.log(checkboxes[i].checked); //returns undefined
 }
```

Do you have any Ideas how to read all Boxes at once?

---

Edit #1 - More Code

index.js

```
angular.module('votes', ['ngMaterial'])

.controller("VoteMainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
        var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
        if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
            if (fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
                fn();
            }
        } else {
            this.$apply(fn);
        }
    };

    register = [];

    //var to store database content and add it to page
    $scope.ideas;

    //Downloading Database stuff as JSON
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./api",
        async: true,
        success: function (content) {
            for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
                register.push({
                    [content[i].id]: {
                        checked: false
                    }
                })
            }
            $scope.ideas = content;
            $scope.safeApply();
        },
    });


    function checkChecked() {
        const checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("md-checkbox");
        for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            console.log(checkboxes[i].checked);
        }
    }
})
```

index.jade

```
    form(id="login" method="post")
       md-card(ng-repeat="n in ideas")
          md-card-content
             span
             md-checkbox(type="checkbox" id='n.id') {{n.idea}}
          md-input-container
             label Andere Idee?
             md-icon search
             input(name='idea', ng-model='idea', id='idea', type='text')
         div(layout="column")
             md-button(type='submit', class="md-raised md-primary unselectable")
                 | Senden!
```

Comment: Can you add your full code please, html and all? I also can't see you using `scope` anywhere.

Comment: for loop is not asynchronous, if its data from database its should be angular.foreach and please add more code

Comment: @ZombieChowder Added more Code!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with `ng-list` and `ng-model`:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppController">
  <ng-list>
    <ng-list-item ng-repeat="n in ideas">
      <p>{{n.id}}: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="n.isChecked"></p>
    </ng-list-item>
  </ng-list>
  <p>Current state of model: {{ ideas }}</p>
</div>
<p>Current state of model: {{ ideas }}</p>
```

**Angular**

angular
  .module("MyApp", ['ngMessages'])
  .controller('MyAppController', AppController);

```
function AppController($scope) {
  $scope.ideas = [{
    id: 193872768,
    isChecked: false
  },{
    id: 238923113,
    isChecked: false
  }];
}
```

## <kbd>[Demo](http://codepen.io/brandonscript/pen/ygXXOK/)</kbd>

This also works with the material design counterparts, `md-list` and `md-checkbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title asks about assigning ids but Your question, which you wrote at the very end is

> "Do you have any Ideas how to read all Boxes at once?"

So if you wanna do something with multiple or all checkbox elements you should assign them some css class, say "idea-checkbox".

Then in css styles or in jQuery you can access all those checkboxes at once by using the dotted syntax of ".idea-checkbox".

css ids are used to distinctively access any one html element and classes are used to get access to all the elements at once which has that class.

You can also try to the use angular's "track by n.id" syntax if you want to track them by their id.

Comment: This isn't the recommended approach when using a model-view-* framework like Angular. It breaks the data model when you try to parse the DOM to enumerate values, and has a rather significant implications when you add more complex behavior into an app.